# for multi-tasking training should I use big datasets as one file or each table as one csv?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

Assuming we want to create a dataset of books.
There would be dataset A: id_book, title, Author, Subject, Topic, Body [paragraph 1,2,3], Sites ...

I was wondering what if i split each book into one dataset xy each, in varius forms but not always the same, always linking to the dataset A [id_book]

Comment: hi @Magos Xiaomi, welcome to the forum. I'm not sure I understand your question, but will try to answer anyway. The most natural way to represent your dataset can depend on many things, but certainly one choice would be a single row per book with a column for each input attribute: id_book, title, author, subject, topic, body, sites, etc. as you describe. If you don't think that's doable please describe what the problem is, and we can make other suggestions.